# Check if the current time is between other times

Tags: objective-c, time

I am working on a project that requires my application to store times (the start and end points of classes) and whenever the app is opened, it needs to check if the current time is between any of those intervals, and do something accordingly. The main problem I am having with NSDateFromComponents is that it does not work after the specified date. I apologize if this is an obvious question, but I am a beginner.

Sincerely,

HBhargava

Comment: Use the compare: function that exists in the NSDate class. Your previous question dated Nov 4th uses this, so you were already on the right track.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if current local time is between two times (ignoring the date portion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108223/determine-if-current-local-time-is-between-two-times-ignoring-the-date-portion)

Answer (score 5):

If your times are `NSDate` objects:

```
if ( ([currentTime compare:otherTime1] == NSOrderedDescending) &&
     ([currentTime compare:otherTime2] == NSOrderedAscending) ) {

}
```

---

See also documentation reference there [NSDate –compare:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:)